# about ODBC connection string using .net

Tags: vb.net, odbc

i am getting error when i connect to oracle DB. am using the connection string statement using ODBC DRIVER. i want to get some data from orcle db and bind it into some control. oracle client is installed in my machine.

```
my db name is PINDB it's in another server. Not in localhost. 
am creating oracle driver named as obdialer il localhost
local host ip adress is 10.103.1.166
the DB is placed in this server (IP 172.23.6.217)
user id is RAM 
password is RAM 

in my programme am using the connection string as like this.

code
----
conn.ConnectionString = ("Driver ={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};server=172.23.6.217.PINDB;Uid =OEARENEWAL;Pwd =OEARENEWAL;Persist Security Info=False;Trusted_Connection=Yes")
try
  con.open()
  ----------
  ----------
 catch ex as exception
    msgbox(ex.message)
 end try



i didnt get any error and also the values are not bind to that particular control.
pls help me to correct the error in connectionstring.
```

Comment: I'd remove the credentials from your connection string.

Comment: What is the error message you received?

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to [this example](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#p17) your connection string is basically correct, but try remocing the last two properties. It's not a trusted connection when you specify a user name and a password:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};server=172.23.6.217.PINDB;Uid=OEARENEWAL;Pwd=OEARENEWAL"
```